# Why aren't the changes reflected, I made in the GUI?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

There is a vague thing going on.

I downloaded a java project with all the libraries it uses. I set it up in netbeans. Now if I make any change in the GUI, it doesn't get reflected. But if I make a jar file of the project by `clean and build option`, and run it through the command prompt, the changes get reflected.

I have never faced this problem before ! What could be the reason for this ? The same thing happens if use the eclipse IDE.`(The changes aren't reflected)`

What happens is that, the default project always runs. The project that I downloaded.It doesn't include my modification.

*Note : The build automatically option is already enabled for both netbeans and eclipse*

Answer (score 0):

Faced long back

It means the project not building automatically.

Checking that build automatically option,resolves the problem.

[image]

Comment: Try with closing the project and then reopen and validate.

Comment: @saplingPro Looking weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's this:

In Eclipse: Take a look at the run-config and the classpath-configuration. There are several ways to include code in the classpath.

One is to include a jar that has been build somewhere else, maybe by maven, or as an external library. That is added with the Buttons "add JARS" or "add external JARS". These jars are not built by eclipse.

And there is a way to include code from an internal eclipse Project. That is done with the button "add Project". This is the code that is built by eclipse.

Maybe your GUI-code has been added to the classpath as a JAR and not as a Project. Try to add your GUI-Sources as a eclipse-project to the classpath.

Greetings

Comment: It's possible to have the GUI-sources as a project in your workspace, without having it on the classpath as a project. This is quite common if you have a big workspace with multiple projects that are build as maven artefacts. In that case you would build those projects by maven on the console. Maven would create JARs from that and you could include that jars in the run-config instead of the workspace-project.

Comment: Did you take a look into Run->Run Configurations...->Classpath?

Comment: Well, it must be something else then... Maybe its a hint that the Problem occurs in two IDEs... It's unlikely that the reason can be found in the IDE config then... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute Eclipse and NetBeans as Administrator? Try to do so and re-build the project.

Other option is to check file permissions.

Comment: yeah I am running them as administrator

Comment: Have you tried to open the files with a text editor to see if in fact the changes are being reflected?

Comment: Try to see where netbeans and eclipse are generating the files of the normal compilation and delete them. I'm just guessing here, you got a hard one